# Partitioning existing LVM physical volume and Create new LVM physical volume

Tags: centos, partition, lvm, openstack

My goal is to create new *LVM physical volume* named *sda3*.
I installed the Centos 7.5 in such partitioning:

```
   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048     2099199     1048576   83  Linux
/dev/sda2         2099200   468877311   233389056   8e  Linux LVM

Disk /dev/mapper/centos-root: 222.9 GB, 222885314560 bytes, 435322880 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/mapper/centos-swap: 10.7 GB, 10733223936 bytes, 20963328 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/mapper/centos-home: 5368 MB, 5368709120 bytes, 10485760 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
```

Actually, I have 3 partitions, `swap`, `home` and `root` which the OS is installed on the `root` partition. I tried to create a new *LVM physical volume* using the command `pvcreate` but it errors:

```
Device /dev/sda3 not found.
```

and when I tried `/dev/sda2` it says:

```
Can't open /dev/sda2 exclusively.  Mounted filesystem?
```

So I guess I should do the following steps to create a new *LVM physical volume*:

1. Repartition(resize) the *sda2* and create a new partition named *sda3*
2. Unmount *sda3* and now I can create a new *LVM physical volume* from *sda3*

The question is how can I resize the `root`(*sda2*) to make space for new partition *sda3* while the OS is installed on the *sda2*?

In the following, I add some related command outputs.

Here is the output of the command `lvmdiskscan`

```
  /dev/centos/root [    <207.58 GiB] 
  /dev/sda1        [       1.00 GiB] 
  /dev/centos/swap [     <10.00 GiB] 
  /dev/sda2        [    <222.58 GiB] LVM physical volume
  /dev/centos/home [       5.00 GiB] 
  3 disks
  1 partition
  0 LVM physical volume whole disks
  1 LVM physical volume
```

and here is the output of `lsblk` command:

```
sda               8:0    0 465.8G  0 disk 
├─sda1            8:1    0     1G  0 part /boot
└─sda2            8:2    0 464.8G  0 part 
  ├─centos-root 253:0    0 451.9G  0 lvm  /
  ├─centos-swap 253:1    0   7.9G  0 lvm  [SWAP]
  └─centos-home 253:2    0     5G  0 lvm  /home
```

The `lvs` command:

```
 LV   VG     Attr       LSize    Pool Origin Data%  Meta%  Move Log Cpy%Sync Convert
  home centos -wi-ao----    5.00g                                                    
  root centos -wi-ao---- <207.58g                                                    
  swap centos -wi-ao----  <10.00g
```

The `vgs` command:

```
VG     #PV #LV #SN Attr   VSize   VFree
  centos   1   3   0 wz--n- 222.57g    0
```

The `pvs` command:

```
PV         VG     Fmt  Attr PSize   PFree
  /dev/sda2  centos lvm2 a--  222.57g    0
```

Comment: Why would you want to create another physical volume (PV)?

Comment: I want to use it as the `OpenStack Cinder volume group`. I tried `sda2` but it was mounted (running the OS)

Comment: Kindly add the output of lvs vgs and pvs command.

Comment: @erTugRul has been Added.

Comment: Forgot to ask you to show the output of df -Th. My bad. Kindly add that one also

Answer (score 0):

You have a problem. Your `/dev/centos/root` LV is about 207 GiB in size, and together with `/dev/centos/swap` and `/dev/centos/home` it looks like your `/dev/sda2` PV is fully in use. By default, CentOS uses a XFS filesystem **which cannot be shrunk**, neither as online nor offline operation, other than by backing up its contents, destroying the filesystem and recreating it in smaller size. Under such conditions, you should always initially configure your filesystems to be as small as reasonable, and be prepared to **extend** them if needed, since XFS offers a robust on-line extension mechanism.

To get free space for `/dev/sda3` partition/PV, you would first need to shrink the `/dev/centos/root` filesystem, then shrink the LV to match, make sure the free extents are at the end of the disk (using `pvmove` to rearrange them if necessary) then `pvresize` to shrink the PV, then edit the partition table to shrink the actual `/dev/sda2` partition... a lot of work.

If you don't have anything too complicated on the system yet, the easiest way would probably be to backup everything necessary, and then completely reinstall CentOS 7.5, this time either configuring the installer to create an empty `/dev/sda3` partition for you, or otherwise ensuring that the space won't get added to any filesystem. In cases like this, the automatic partitioning feature of the OS installer is definitely *not* your friend.

Comment: Thanks, If I had created partitions as standard partition and not LVM at the OS installation, I could shrink it easily and make it LMV group, yes?

Comment: A bit less steps perhaps, but the first step, shrinking an XFS filesystem, would remain just as impossible.

Comment: Thanks, I want to allocate 100G to sda2 and make free about 200G and create new sda3. I wanted to use the command `pvresize --setphysicalvolumesize 100G /dev/sda2` but according to your advice I think I should rearrange data using to prevent data loss. Could give me an example of the command `pvmove`, pls?

Comment: Please add the output of `lsblk` into your question post.

Comment: I edited the post and add the output of the `lsblk` command.

Comment: Is that from the same system? Your previous commands indicate that the `/dev/centos/root` LV is about 208 GiB, but `lsblk` says 451.9G. Like @erTugRul, I'd also want to see the output of `df -Th` to verify a few things, like the actual filesystem types, sizes and amounts of space actually used.